How to run LangChains getting-started examples and getting output?
I'm going to learn LangChain and stumble upon their Getting Started section. Because it doesn't work and I'm curious if I am the only person where LangChain examples don't work.
This is their tutorial I am talking about. https://python.langchain.com/docs/get_started/quickstart/
Let's use the very first example:
llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=api_key)
llm.invoke("how can langsmith help with testing?")

I wrote some initializing code as well to make ChatOpenAI work:
import os
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

api_key = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")

llm = ChatOpenAI(openai_api_key=api_key)
llm.invoke("how can langsmith help with testing?")

The invoke function seems to be executed as I can't see any error message. But I also can't see any further output. Nothing happens.
They even wrote "We can also guide its response with a prompt template.". However,  there is not response.
Who can explain to me, what is happening here? And can you probably recommend me a better tutorial instead of that from LangChain?

llm.invoke returns a response object. In the Python console, uncaptured return values would be printed to the console. But in a Python script (*.py), uncaptured return values are ignored, so you'll have to capture and print it yourself.

The page mentions that it is assumed the examples are ran in a Jupyter notebook, where output might be returned differently than elsewhere

As mentioned in the comments, the documentation assumes that the code is being written in a Jupyter notebook. The return type of the invoke method is a BaseMessage. If you want to see the response object, first assign the response of the invoke function to a variable:
response = llm.invoke("how can langsmith help with testing?")

and then print its value:
print(response)

If you're only interested in the text of the response, use this instead:
print(response.content)


OPENAI_API_KEY = os.getenv("OPENAI_API_KEY")
from langchain_openai import ChatOpenAI

def ask_gpt(prompt, temperature, max_tokens):

    """
    Sends a prompt to the GPT-3.5 Turbo model and returns the AI response.

    Parameters:
    prompt (str): The input prompt to send to the GPT-3.5 Turbo model.
    temperature (float): The temperature parameter controls the randomness of the output. Higher values (e.g., 0.8) make the output more random, while lower values (e.g., 0.2) make it more focused and deterministic.
    max_tokens (int): The maximum number of tokens in the response. This parameter can be used to limit the length of the generated text.

    Returns:
    str: The AI response generated by the GPT-3.5 Turbo model.
    """

    llm = ChatOpenAI(api_key=OPENAI_API_KEY, temperature=temperature, max_tokens=max_tokens, model="gpt-3.5-turbo")
    AI_Response = llm.invoke(prompt)
    return AI_Response.content

